# Can dependent child change status to independent in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, dependent-visa

I got UK pre-settlement status under EU settlement Scheme as a dependent of my EU national ( ITALY) Father. My nationality is Bangladeshi. However My BRP is valid for 5 years and I got that on December-2019. I want to  change my dependency to independent now . Is there any way ?

Comment: If you cease to be dependent on your father, won't you lose your right to live in the UK?

Comment: Actually I don't know , this is why I am asking .